# php pushing into an array within a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, merge

I'm generating an array of results within a loop, and I want to add to the array within the loop. Obviously array push will not work as these are key, value pairs.

```
foreach($res as $ap){
    $this->db->where('event_time >', $ev_time);
    $this->db->where('event_ID', $ap['event_id']);
    $query = $this->db->get('events');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $linked[] = $result[0]; // <-- want to add key, value pair within this
        $linked['new_key'] = $new_value; // <-- did not work :(
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Also this array later gets merged with another array. If I add an extra key, value pair to this that isn't in the other array, will that break the merge?

Comment: $linked['new_key'] = $new_value; should be $linked['new_key'][] = $new_value; I believe

Comment: what is $new_value? it isnt being set anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$i = 0;
foreach($res as $ap){
    $this->db->where('event_time >', $ev_time);
    $this->db->where('event_ID', $ap['event_id']);
    $query = $this->db->get('events');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $linked[$i] = $result[0]; // <-- want to add key, value pair within this
        $linked[$i]['new_key'] = $new_value;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The `$i` will enable you to add the new value into the same element as the `$result[0]` was was written to.

Comment: np :) glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($res as $ap){
    $this->db->where('event_time >', $ev_time);
    $this->db->where('event_ID', $ap['event_id']);
    $query = $this->db->get('events');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $linked[] = $result[0]; // <-- want to add key, value pair within this

        $linked['new_key'][] = $new_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That creates a new array within the array. Not what I want.

Comment: `Array ([0] => Array([key1] => val1 [key2] => val2 [NEW KEY] => NEW VAL))` is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
$myarray[] = array($key, $value);
```